# Given a string return all permutations by removing characters and maintaining the order

Tags: string, permutation

I believe this is mostly a problem of vocabulary and I expect that given the correct vocabulary I would have already found an answer. I have a string of any length and I want to return all "permutations" of this string while maintaining the order of the characters and the differences in the permutations is achieved by removal of characters.

Traditionally the answer to permutations of a string is: given a string "ABC" return ["ABC", "ACB", "BAC", "BCA", "CBA", "CAB"] using a recursive tree or any number or other algorithms.

However I want: given a string "ABC" return ["A", "AB", "ABC", "AC", "B", "BC", "C"]

I think my use of the term permutations is what is tripping me up.

What is the correct terminology to find algorithms that would achieve this? Or any thoughts on what to look at to get a start on solving this?

Comment: You're looking to generate the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) - the set of all subsets of a set.

Answer (score 0):

```
s='ABC'
p=['']
for i in s:
    p += [j+i for j in p]
del p[0]
print(p)
```

Try this, the logic is quite simple, it goes like this (the object p belongs to after every iteration):

```
['']
['', 'A']
['', 'A', 'B', 'AB']
['', 'A', 'B', 'AB','C', 'AC', 'BC', 'ABC']
```

Finally the  item at 0 index is removed and we get a list of all possible permutations!

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to solve it along the same lines as Nothing special albeit in JavaScript and kept infinitely recusing. I also attempting implementing their code in JS, and got as far as my attempts (I'm sure that was down to my inability to code, not his starting code).

The comment above from RaffleBuffle is what sorted it for me: Power Sets led me to looking through algorithms that returned the Power Set of a Set. And I settled on this version which seems fairly quick as well:

```
const listSubSets = (string) => {
  const stringArray = string.split("");
  const getSubSets = (array) => array.reduce(
    (subsets, value) => subsets.concat(
      subsets.map(set => [...set, value])
    ),
    [[]]
  ).map(x => x.join(""));

  return getSubSets(stringArray);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you haven't mentioned the language anywhere.... My bad, I thought it was python... But you should add some code in your question & tag the language... That'll get your question popularity...

Comment: Absolutely no problem, I felt fairly confident it was a definition problem and if I had the magic words I could look it up myself. The python didn't bother me at all, I just couldn't translate it effectively.